# Mise en place (fr) or prep (en)

Tags: translation

What is the best german translation for the french word "mise en place" or the english word equivalent "prep" in cooking ?

Comment: What do dictionaries suggest, and why isn't their information sufficient? We expect that people put a reasonable amount of own work into their questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In professional cooking, a lot of French terms are used. [*Mise en place*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_Place) is the correct term in German, too, and it's the only one that I can think of that really fits cooking.

If you insist on translating it, good verbs that are used in other crafts are *etwas bereitlegen* or *sich etwas zurechtlegen*, there are no commonly used nouns <strike>"Bereitlegung"</strike> or <strike>"Zurechtlegung"</strike> though (see comments for some exceptions). You could use *das Bereitlegen* or *das Zurechtlegen*, but you won't hear those being used regularly either.

*Bereitstellung* comes near, but is kind of ambiguous and not self-explainatory. *Arbeitsvorbereitung* ("preparation for working") or just *Vorbereitung* ("preparation") are a bit more general, but it's probably quite clear what they comprise in the context of cooking.

Comment: In professional cooking and restaurant business *Mise en place* is the term to use in Germany. So +1.

Comment: "Bereitlegung" is actually used in some contexts, see for example "Ordentliche und ungefährliche Aufbewahrung bzw. Bereitlegung von Handwerkszeugen können durch geeignete Hilfsmittel erleichtert werden" (occupational safety advice by the [Berufsgenossenschaft Holz und Metall](https://www.bghm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Arbeitsschuetzer/Gesetze_Vorschriften/Informationen/209-001.pdf)). But it's clearly not used widely and has a very bureaucratic vibe.

Comment: And interestingly, "Zurechtlegung" is used occasionally as well, but with a different meaning. It refers more to a perspective, a way of looking at something. For example, Nietzsche is quoted with "In unserer Macht steht die Zurechtlegung des Leidens zum Segen" (roughly "It's within our power to look at suffering as a blessing"). But I agree that neither, "Bereitlegung" or "Zurechtlegung" is commonly used, not in the kitchen or otherwise ;)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: I agree, these are words that can basically just be "made up" on the spot in some contexts. I edited again, I'm not sure how to make this clear in short English terms.